# How can I substitute a value if a field is null with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following report:

```
var menuItems = _menuRepository.GetPk(pk)
                .Where(m => m.Status == "00")
                .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
                .Select(m => new MenuItem
                {
                    PartitionKey = m.PartitionKey,
                    RowKey = m.RowKey,
                    Order = m.Order,
                    Order1 = m.Order.Substring(0, 1),
                    Order2 = m.Order.Substring(2, 1),
                    Order3 = m.Order.Substring(4, 1),
                    Order4 = m.Order.Substring(6, 2),
                    Title = m.Title,
                    Type = m.Type,
                    Link = m.Link,
                    TextLength = m.TextLength
                });
```

This fails if there are some records where Order is null or empty. Is there a way that I can substitute a string of 8 zeros if m.Order is null or empty and substitute one zero for all of the Order.Substrings?

Comment: What fails? The Substring or the OrderBy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator:

```
var menuItems = _menuRepository.GetPk(pk)
    .Where(m => m.Status == "00")
    .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
    .Select(m =>
                {
                    var orderOrEmpty = m.Order ?? "00000000";
                    return new MenuItem
                                {
                                    PartitionKey = m.PartitionKey,
                                    RowKey = m.RowKey,
                                    Order = m.Order,
                                    Order1 = orderOrEmpty.Substring(0, 1),
                                    Order2 = orderOrEmpty.Substring(2, 1),
                                    Order3 = orderOrEmpty.Substring(4, 1),
                                    Order4 = orderOrEmpty.Substring(6, 2),
                                    Title = m.Title,
                                    Type = m.Type,
                                    Link = m.Link,
                                    TextLength = m.TextLength
                                };
                });
```

Comment: You mean null-coalescing operator

Answer (score 2):

```
Order1 = m.Order == null ? "0" : m.Order.Substring(0, 1)
```

The conditional operator (?:) also called Ternary Operator returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.

```
<boolean condition> ? <value returned if true> : <value returned if false>;
```

Comment: To tailor this to his question, it'd be `Order1 = m.Order == null ? "00000000" : m.Order.Substring(0, 1)`

You can read more on the ternary operator [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I think the wants the whole `Order` to be `"00000000"`. I corrected my example.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to replace the result of the `m.Order.SubString` calls with 0's if it's `null` or empty.  The way to do this is to just use a string of all 0's if the `m.Order` value is null / empty

```
.Select(m => {
   var order = m.Order ?? "00000000";
   return new MenuItem {      
     PartitionKey = m.PartitionKey,
     RowKey = m.RowKey,
     Order = m.Order,
     Order1 = order.Substring(0, 1),
     Order2 = order.Substring(2, 1),
     Order3 = order.Substring(4, 1),
     Order4 = order.Substring(6, 2),
     Title = m.Title,
     Type = m.Type,
     Link = m.Link,
     TextLength = m.TextLength
  }});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Order1 = (m.Order ?? "00000000").Substring(0, 1)
```

or

```
Order1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Order) ? "0" : m.Order.Substring(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write an extension method `IfNotNull` and use as

```
m.Order.IfNotNull(s=>s.Substring(0,1),"0") 
//or
m.Order.IfNotNull(s=>s.Substring(6,2),"00")
//or
m.Order.IfNotNull(s=>s.Substring(6,2))
```

.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static TOut IfNotNull<T, TOut>(this T target, Func<T, TOut> valueFunc,TOut defValue=default(TOut))
        where T : class
    {
        return target == null ? defValue : valueFunc(target);
    }
}
```